# PHP lockfunction with fopen seems fails

Tags: php, locking

I've written a lockfunction to protect functions from running simultaneously. But I'm getting the idea that the function isn't performing well and the function might run simultaneously when started within a couple of seconds.

My lock function:

```
function lockFunction($function){
    $lock = SERVER_ROOT.'/lock/'.$function.'.lock';
    $f = @fopen($lock, 'x');
    if($f === false){
        # Lockfile exists, script is running
        return false;
    }else{
        # Script is not running, now locked
        fclose($f);
        return true;
    }
}
```

When the function is done, I unlock the function

```
function unlockFunction($function){
  @unlink(SERVER_ROOT.'/lock/'.$function.'.lock');
}
```

How I use the function:

**script.php**

```
if(lockFunction('functiontolock')){
    # Run code that may not be run simultaneously

    # sleep just as example of runtime.
    sleep(10);    

    unlockFunction('functiontolock');
}
```

Can this cause issues when `script.php` is run twice within e.g. 2 seconds.

**Note**
The server where this is running on uses cluster technology, meaning that files are on a file server, database on a different server etc. The files are accessed via network. Don't know it that slows down this function.

Comment: script is working fine for me.

Comment: Are you sure you get correct paths on `SERVER_ROOT`?

Comment: Even i ran script more than 2 times. all are get failed because lock file exists. and first execution deletes the file aftet 10 sec.

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam, SERVER_ROOT is correct. If I run it twice on my own development I'm not getting issues. I'm going to try this on my production environment.

Comment: Okay what is issue now?

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam, I can't break my own code. So probably this is not the issue I'm having.